# how to back up an app's data manually?

Tags: backup

I am able to backup my app's data from the `root/data/data/you.package.name` directory by just moving it to SD card manually. however, when i reverse the process,                                                                                                               AKA paste the data back to simulate a restore, the app just force closes, i have tried it with a bunch of apps and noticed the same reaction. Where am i wrong?

Comment: Permissions messed up I suppose. Don't copy into SD card directly but make a tar archive which preserves permission of source files (app's data). Restore data in such a manner that it restores the same permissions, restore SELinux context (in case SELinux is in enforcing mode). BTW, which Android device and version are you using?

Comment: Also, before restoring, make sure the app whose data you're trying to restore is completely stopped. Do so using command-line or Settings app. Also make sure you clear its data before restoring yours. Perhaps my answer can help here: [Backup an app's complete data when phone is stuck in bootloop](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/137043)

Comment: permissions are only required for the system folders my dawg not user data my homie told me

Comment: Whatever your homie told you, @Firelord is right: `/data/data` uses an EXTFS file system allowing for granular permissions and ownership, while SDCard uses FAT which does ***not*** allow for that. By copying to SD you "disowned" the files. After having copied them back, they had the wrong ownership, so the app becomes unable to access (or even overwrite) them. Unable ro read/write its data, it crashes then (expectable behaviour). // See our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for how to do backups. *Helium* or `adb backup` are there for this kind of job.

Comment: @Izzy I feel quite odd by correcting you, but any mountpoint listed under /storage is a FUSE, not a FAT.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman True it's FUSE, but AFAIK it *acts like FAT* (compatibility stuff). What file system is FUSE, please? :) It's not a *physical* file system on its own, but rather an implementation (FUSE stands for File System in User Space, which opposes the "System Space" aka "kernel space"). There're several file systems using FUSE: SSHFS, DAVFS and others have FUSE implementations. For details, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace): it's a "virtual file system" providing a "bridge" to the actual kernel interfaces.

Comment: @Izzy Nice point. You're correct.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Firelord just [offered proof](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28347636#28347636): *[sdcard program does the job of mounting FUSE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-5.1.1_r36/sdcard/sdcard.c) and in [config.jd](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+/android-5.1.1_r36/src/devices/tech/storage) is mentioned that the sdcard program is used by some devices to expose internal storage through FUSE.*

Answer (score 5):

<sup>As there's no more feedback, I'll sum up from the comments for those coming up with a similar issue:</sup>

[Firelord correctly pointed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/139948/16575#comment-179448) this most likely is an issue with file permissions. Internal storage uses a file system supporting [granular file permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions)**<sup>1</sup>** – which are not supported by the file system used on SD cards<sup>**2**</sup>. So the copy of all the contents on your SD card has lost that information, and ownership got lost<sup>**3**</sup>. So copying this back to your internal storage, it still has the wrong ownership, so the app cannot access it properly. Not expecting this<sup>**4**</sup>, the app will of course misbehave: an [exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) will occur without being handled, so the app crashes (force-close).

For those who checked with the `mount` command and now argue *you're wrong, SD card doesn't use FAT but FUSE!* – True it's FUSE, but in this case it *acts like FAT.* What file system is FUSE, please? :) It's not a *physical* file system on its own, but rather a *virtual* one (FUSE stands for [File System in User Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), which opposes the "System Space" aka "kernel space") providing a "bridge" to the actual kernel interfaces. There're several file systems using FUSE: SSHFS, DAVFS and others have FUSE implementations. Again it was [Firelord bringing up some backing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28347636#28347636) to my claim: *[sdcard program does the job of mounting FUSE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-5.1.1_r36/sdcard/sdcard.c) and in [config.jd](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+/android-5.1.1_r36/src/devices/tech/storage) is mentioned that the sdcard program is used by some devices to expose internal storage through FUSE.*

**Conclusion:** You took a complete wrong approach to [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) and [restore](/questions/tagged/restore) here. If you really wanted to deal with that on the file system level, you should have used a tool like [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) (which is available and usually pre-installed on Android devices) to archive the contents while preserving permissions (the resulting "tarball" can then be copied to SD card, and the contents still be extracted to their original location properly). OTOH, as our [backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) will tell you, this is exactly what [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) backup or apps like [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) and [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) are for.

---

<sup>**1:** on older Android versions this often was [YAFFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAFFS), on newer it's [Extfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extfs)</sup>
<sup>**2:** usually [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_systems#FAT)</sup>
<sup>**3:** or rather "reset" to the defaults used for content stored on the SD card</sup>
<sup>**4:** a normal user cannot do such stuff, as `/data/data/<package_name>` is not accessible to anyone but its owner and root</sup>